# How to change color of new Diff Markers in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

I want to change the Diff Marker colors that appear just to the right of the number column in sublime text 3 editors.

https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/incremental_diff.html

I tried going to `preference -> Settings` but cannot find any property `line_diff_added` or `line_diff_modifies`.

How should I update these colors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The colors for the `mini_diff` indicators are specified by the color scheme that you're using; the `line_diff_added` and other items you mention are contained in that file.

To modify them you can create a customization on whatever color scheme you're currently using by creating a `sublime-color-scheme` file in your `User` package that is named after your color scheme, which contains the customized colors.

To determine your color scheme, check the `color_scheme` setting in your preferences; you can also determine where your `User` package is by using `Preferences > Browse Packages` if you're unsure.

When you create such a file in your `User` package, Sublime will load the base file first and then apply your changes on top; hence you can adjust just the parts of the color scheme that you want while retaining all of the defaults.

As an example, if you use the `Monokai` color scheme that ships with Sublime, then creating a file named `Monokai.sublime-color-scheme` in your `User` package with the following contents:

```
{
    "globals":
    {
        "line_diff_added": "var(yellow2)",
        "line_diff_modified": "var(blue)",
        "line_diff_deleted": "var(red)",
        "line_diff_width": "5"
    },
}
```

Will create diff markers similar to this:

[image: Sample of above color scheme]

In this particular example, the colors being referenced are specified as variables in the base `Monokai.sublime-color-scheme` file; you're free to choose whatever colors you like for this, of course. You can use `View Package File` from the command palette to peek at the color scheme you're using if you want to see what it's doing on its own.

Note also that if you happen to be using a legacy color scheme of type `tmTheme`, the above still applies; if you were using `SomeLegacyTheme.tmTheme`, then you would create `SomeLegacyTheme.sublime-color-scheme` in your `User` package to customize it (note that the extension is different).

See the docs on [Color Schemes](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/color_schemes.html) (and in particular on [customizing them](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/color_schemes.html#customization)) for more detailed information on this, including how you can specify the colors you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding new key to *.tmTheme file.

To see which *.tmTheme file exactly is used in your case:
preferences - color_scheme key

Answer (score 1):

Just like this in your *.tmTheme file.

```xml
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>line_diff_width</key>
            <string>8</string>
            [...]
        </dict>
```